# Solution to congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am studying abstract mathematics and I came across this in my textbook.
Example: Find a solution to the congruence $$5x\equiv11\pmod{19}$$
It starts off the solution with: If there is a solution, then, by Theorem 3.1.4, there is a solution within the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,18\}$.

Theorem 3.1.4 states: For a given modulus $m$, each integer is congruent to exactly one of the numbers in this set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,m-1\}$.

My question is: how does the theorem imply that $x$ must be in this above set?

Comment: Because $19-1=18$?

Comment: Aha. So with the edit, is your question really about why $0$ disappeared?

Comment: When a number is divided by 19, what about possible remainders?

Comment: Hint: $5\cdot 4\equiv 1$,  $5\cdot 4\cdot ?\equiv 11$?

Comment: @Théophile my bad thanks for pointing out the zero's, I know the possible remainders of an integer divided is within the set, but how does that imply the x in 5x also has to be within the set

Comment: I see. The $5$ doesn't matter. The theorem is really just telling you a property about all integers, including $x$.

Comment: are you asking why does the theorem imply there exists some $l \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x = \frac{19l+11}{5} \in \{0,1,...,19-1\}$?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame The theorem doesn't imply that. The theorem is simply saying that all integers are congruent to something modulo $19$. Whether there's a solution to the equation or not is another matter.

Comment: that's why I asked what I asked cause I do not see how it implies that either.

Comment: My apologies, I should have better formulated my question. In a more general case if we have a,b,m that are fixed numbers and we know there is a solution to $ax\equiv b(\mod{m})$, how can we conclude that there is a solution for $x$ such that $x\in\{0,1,...,m-1\}$

Comment: @Nabeel Your question is formulated fine as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good critique. The theorem does *not* imply that *by itself*. Rather, we need to use further properties of congruences to make that inference. Let's derive that inference in further detail.

Working $\bmod 19,\,$ if an integer $\,n\,$ is a root of $\,5x\equiv 11$ then the theorem implies that $\,\color{#c00}{n\equiv \bar n}\,$ for $\,0\le n < 19\ $ (viz. $\,\bar n = n\bmod 19).\,$ Then by the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\, 11\equiv 5\color{#c00}n\equiv 5 \color{#c00}{\bar n},\,$ so $\,5\bar n\equiv 11\,$ by transitivity of congruence, i.e if $\,n\,$ is a root then so too is every integer $\,\bar n\equiv n.$

More generally, if $\,f(x)\,$ is a polynomial with *integer* coef's and $n$ is a root of $\,f(x)\,$ then so too is every $\bar n\equiv n,\,$ e.g. $\,\bar n = n\bmod 19$, which follows by applying the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\,\bar n\equiv n\Rightarrow f(\bar n)\equiv f(n)\ $ (which holds because polynomials are compositions of sums and products, so we can inductively apply the Congruence and Power Rules - see the linked proof).

Comment: Thank you so much, it all makes sense now!